# Validation in angularjs not working propoerly

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
 <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="queryCtrl">
      <form name="queryform" ng-submit="submitQuery(queryform.$valid)" novalidate="">
        <legend>SEARCH</legend>
        <div class="form-group" >
          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Criteria 2:</label>
          <input type="text" class="col-sm-4 form-control" name="input" ng-model="query.inputfield" required="" />
         <p ng-show="queryform.input.$invalid && !queryform.input.$pristine" class="help-block">You name is required.</p>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled=!queryform.$valid>Submit</button>
      </form>
```

Explain how i can resolve this issue.can any one explain proper validation procedure in angular .check out my plunker

[Why ng-show is loading in the first place ?](https://plnkr.co/edit/XCTEAhzH0mDJ10RYy5Jn?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

validation works in this format

`ng-show = "formname.inputname.$touched && formname.inputname.$invalid"`

if the form is as below

```
<form name="formname">
 <input name="inputname" ng-model="inputName" >
</form>
```

you can see all properties of an input by writing `{{ formname.inputname | json }}` in HTML , also if you want to see only error than can use `{{ formname.inputname.$error | json }}`

see the [working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/DQD1Wt5pe0cCZJhubQGX?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you :). plunker helped

Comment: yes. fot that it would be `formname.inputname.$error.pattern`